# Using Javascript to shorten the length of a html page

Tags: php, javascript, html

If anyone can help. I have been developing my pages in html and css. Now i have this page that has become lenghthy and tedious to scroll and get what you want. I used the `:target` tag on css to break the page into sections but it does not work on some browsers. I have been playing around with javascript with no success. May anyone help me with the js scripts that i should use in the page such that when someone loads the page it only shows the internal links which will serve as a table of contents and when the user click on the an internal link, only that section that is linked with the div displays or pops up?

Or alternatively is there a way i can use PHP?

```
 <div>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#introduction">Introduction to 
antimicrobials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#antifungals">Antifungal Drugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#antiprotozoals">Antiprotozoal Drugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#antihelminthics">Antihelminthic Drugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#antibacterials">Antibacterials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#aminoglycosides">Aminoglycosides</a></li>
            <li><a href="#antifolates">Antifolate Drugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fluoroquinolones">Fluoroquinolones</a></li>
            <li><a href="#antimycobacterials">Antimycobacterial 
Drugs</a></li>            

            </ul>

            <div id="introduction">
            Viruses: Smallest pathogens, programmed to infect only certain 
body cells. Virus uses a body cells to reproduce itself it cannot be 
treated with medication.

Bacteria: single celled microorganism, 1000 different bacteria, but 100 
cause disease.
- Bacteria can be treated with antibiotics.
- Some bacteria are becoming immune to certain antibiotics.
- Bacterial Diseases: Strep throat, Tuberculosis Gonorrhea, Syphilis

Fungi: single celled or multicellular plantlike organism
- Fungi can cause diseases of the skin, mucous membrane, and lungs.
- Fungi Diseases: Athlete’s foot, Ringworm, Jock itch, Nail infections, 
Candidiasis</div>



<div id="antifungals">
Amphotericin B continues to be an important drug for the treatment of 
systemic fungal infections. However, several azoles and echinocandins are 
proving to be just as effective in some systemic mycoses with less risk of 
toxic effects.
</div>


<div id="antiprotozoals">
Drugs for Malaria:

Malaria is one of the most common diseases worldwide and a leading cause of 
death. Plasmodium species that infect humans (P falciparum, P malariae, P 
ovale, P vivax) undergo a primary developmental stage in the liver and then 
parasitize erythrocytes. P falciparum and P malariae have only 1 cycle of 
liver cell invasion. The other species have a dormant hepatic stage 
responsible for recurrent infections and relapses. Primary tissue 
schizonticides (eg, primaquine) kill schizonts in the liver, whereas blood 
schizonticides (eg, chloroquine, quinine) kill these parasitic forms only 
in the erythrocyte. Sporonticides (proguanil, pyrimethamine) prevent 
sporogony and multiplication in the mosquito.

Drugs: Chloroquine, Quinine, Mefloquine, Primaquine, pyrimethamine, 
proguanil, Sulfadoxine, Dapsone, Doxycycline, Amodiaquine, Atovaquone, 
Halofantrine, Artesunate, Artemether, Dihydroartemisinin

</div>

<div id="antihelminthics">
Antihelminthic drugs have diverse chemical structures, mechanisms of 
action, and properties. Most were discovered by empiric screening methods; 
many act against specific parasites, and few are devoid of significant 
toxicity to host cells. In addition to the direct toxicity of the drugs, 
reactions to dead and dying parasites may cause serious toxicity in 
patients.
</div>

<div id="antibacterials">
Beta-Lactam Antibiotics & Other Cell Wall Synthesis Inhibitors

Penicillins and cephalosporins are the major antibiotics that inhibit 
bacterial cell wall synthesis. They are called beta-lactams because of the 
unusual 4-member ring that is common to all their members. The beta-lactams 
include some of the most effective, widely used, and well-tolerated agents 
available for the treatment of microbial infections. Vancomycin, 
fosfomycin, and bacitracin also inhibit cell wall synthesis but are not 
nearly as important as the beta-lactam drugs. More than 50 antibiotics that 
act as cell wall synthesis inhibitors are currently available, with 
individual spectra of activity that afford a wide range of clinical 
applications.
</div>

<div id="aminoglycosides">
Aminoglycosides are structurally related amino sugars attached by 
glycosidic linkages. They are polar compounds, not absorbed after oral 
administration and must be given intramuscularly, or intravenously for 
systemic effect. They have limited tissue penetration and do not readily 
cross the blood-brain barrier. Glomerular filtration is the major mode of 
excretion, and plasma levels of these drugs are greatly affected by changes 
in renal function. Excretion of aminoglycosides is directly proportional to 
creatinine clearance. With normal renal function, the elimination half-life 
of aminoglycosides is 2–3 h. Dosage adjustments must be made in renal 
insufficiency to prevent toxic accumulation. Monitoring of plasma levels of 
aminoglycosides is important for safe and effective dosage selection and 
adjustment. For traditional dosing regimens (2 or 3 times daily), peak 
serum levels are measured 30–60 min after administration and trough levels 
just before the next dose. With once-daily dosing, peak levels are less 
important since they will naturally be high.
    </div>

    <div id="fluoroquinolones">
  The fluoroquinolones interfere with bacterial DNA synthesis by inhibiting 
topoisomerase II (DNA gyrase), especially in gram-negative organisms and 
topoisomerase IV, especially in gram-positive organisms. They block the 
relaxation of supercoiled DNA that is catalyzed by DNA gyrase, a step 
required for normal transcription and duplication. Inhibition of 
topoisomerase IV by fluoroquinolones interferes with the separation of 
replicated chromosomal DNA during cell division. Fluoroquinolones are 
usually bactericidal against susceptible organisms. Like aminoglycosides, 
the fluoroquinolones exhibit postantibiotic effects, whereby bacterial 
growth continues to be inhibited even after the plasma concentration of the 
drug has fallen below the minimum inhibitory concentration of the bacterium
</div>

<div id="antimycobacterials">
Drugs for Tuberculosis

The major drugs used in tuberculosis are isoniazid (INH), rifampin, 
ethambutol, pyrazinamide, and streptomycin. Actions of these agents on M 
tuberculosis are bactericidal or bacteriostatic depending on drug 
concentration and strain susceptibility. Appropriate drug treatment 
involves antibiotic susceptibility testing of mycobacterial isolates. 
Initiation of treatment of pulmonary tuberculosis usually involves a 3- or 
4-drug combination regimen depending on the known or anticipated rate of 
resistance to isoniazid (INH). Directly observed therapy (DOT) regimens are 
recommended in noncompliant patients and in drug-resistant tuberculosis.
 </div>  

        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use [jquery](http://jquery.com/)

There are some plugin that makes it easy to work with hashs:

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS. Nest all the internal div's into a container and add a class or id attribute to that div. For example:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="introduction">asdfasdfasdfasd</div>
    <div id="fluoroquinolones">more stuff</div>
</div>
```

On default, make the display of all the nested div to none

```
<style type="css/text">
    #container div { display: none; }
</style>
```

I would also recommend attaching an identifier to the list containing the links. And use JavaScript so when you click on the links it will open. I would recommend JQuery for faster development and ease of development.

You could select all the elements using a JavaScript command like so:

```
document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("a")
```

And add an onclick to that that will turn on the selected div element, but turn off every other one (change the CSS display).

-- Edit:
Example JavaScript

```
<script type="javascript/text">
var x = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("a");
var last = "";
for (i in x) {
    x[i].onclick = function(e) {
        var current = this.hash.substr(1);
        if (last!="")
            document.getElementById(last).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById(this.hash.substr(1)).style.display = "block";
        last = current;
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    };
}
</script>
```

This assumes you identified the list element container with the id "test".

Using JQuery would have saved a bunch of keystrokes.

-- edit with fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7B9sP/

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li a').click(function() {
        var getID = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.alldivs').fadeOut();
        $(getID).fadeIn();
        // or $(getID).slideDown();
        // or something you want. see in jquery.com
        // don't forget to use a plugin jquery in you head page html.
        return false;
    });
});
```

The div "introduction", assign `class="alldivs"` to hide and then show the div selectd. I hope I helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a name="introduction" href="#introduction">Introduction to antimicrobials</a></li>
            <li><a name="introduction" href="#antifungals">Antifungal Drugs</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="introduction" class="description">
            Viruses: Smallest pathogens, programmed to infect only certain 
            body cells. Virus uses a body cells to reproduce itself it cannot be 
            treated with medication.
        </div>

        <div id="antifungals" class="description">
            Amphotericin B continues to be an important drug for the treatment of 
             systemic fungal infections. However, several azoles and echinocandins are 
             proving to be just as effective in some systemic mycoses with less risk of 
             toxic effects.
        </div>
     </div>
```

Now consider this your html and then add the following CSS

```
   .description {
       display: none;
    }

    .displaying {
       display: block;
    }
```

And then add the following jquery code in your body. Be sure you import the jquery library on the page.

```
  $('.data-link').on('click', function(event) {
     var id = $(this).attr('name');
     if($('#' + id).hasClass('description')) {
        $('#' + id).removeClass('description').addClass('displaying');
      } else {
        $('#' + id).removeClass('displaying').addClass('description');
      }
   });
```

I wrote a simple jsfiddle to demonstarate that.

http://jsfiddle.net/kG9wn/

The code also hides the div if you click again.